# GetWindowRect give back 0 RECT from Start menu on opening

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My problem is when the start menu opens (i got the EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS via WinEventHook), the GetWindowRect usually gives back {0,0,0,0} RECT and returns with no error.

I made a test code for it (runs until I click the start button then stops with the "Got {0,0,0,0}" (8 times from 10, 2 times it keeps running) )

How can I assure that the GetWindowRect always gives back valid data?

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Start menu");
for (int cnt = 1; ; ++cnt)
{
    RECT r = {0,0,0,0};
    if(GetWindowRect(hwnd, &r))
    {
        if (r.left == 0 && r.top == 0 && r.right == 0 && r.bottom == 0)
        {
            cout << cnt << ": Got {0,0,0,0}";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << cnt << ": Ok" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << cnt << ": Call failed!";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my understanding, this call will be succeeded even without popping it up (works well with Windows 7).

Comment: Yeah, the GetWindowRect always succeeds, but gives back {0,0,0,0} when I click Start button.
I have this problem with Win7 64bit.

Comment: You write that you do this when it gets focus, are you sure it's fully expanded at that point?

Comment: Nope, but the GetWindowRect succeeds with non zero values even if the start menu is hidden

Comment: API won't behave in two different ways across platforms. Please recheck the hook you've made. And also make sure is it really necessary to have the hook overhead?

Comment: I ran my test code on numerous machine with Win 7 (both x86 and x64) in the past few days.
All stopped with "Got {0,0,0,0}" message...

Comment: I see two possible reasons for "Got {0,0,0,0}. Maybe `FindWindow` returns `NULL`, or returns a handle of an empty parent window. It is better to search for the window's classname ("Shell_TrayWnd") than a hardcoded window name. See also [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/hide_vista_start_orb.aspx).

Comment: FindWindow works fine because the test code stops when i push the window button until than it spams "Ok".

Comment: The linked article is also search for window name (VistaStartMenuCaption), and the class of the Start menu is DV2ControlHost and it's not usable because for example the "Jump list" has the same class too.